# SOQL Salesforce Join and Filter for 3 Different Objects

Tags: salesforce, soql

I would appreciate if someone can help me with the following requirement for building a SOQL.

Object1: Event : 
Fields to get: Id, Subject, OwnerId

Object2: EventAttendee : 
Fields to get: EventId, AttendeeId

Object3: User : 
Fields to get: Id, Email

Note: 
Id of Event = EventId of EventAttendee & 
AttendeeId of EventAttendee = Id of user

So the requirement is to lookup Id from Event into EventId of EventAttendee and get the respective AttendeeID, then for the same AttendeeId lookup into user to get the Email address.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to start from Event, go down to Attendees, then up to Users. The table that holds attendees is actually called [EventRelation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm). Something like that should get you started:

```
SELECT Id, Subject, OwnerId,
    (SELECT EventId, RelationId, Relation.Email FROM EventRelations)
FROM Event
```

Comment: we're using api v26, so there's no EventRelations but EventAttendee

Comment: Can you bump up your API version? By modifying the endpoint url if it's SOAP/REST or by changing the class/trigger's metadata? If not - the general idea should be similar, just different name of related list & possibly fields. What do you end up with when you run a "describe" in your tool?

Comment: `SELECT Id, Subject, OwnerId,
    (SELECT EventId, AttendeeId, Attendee.Email FROM EventAttendees)
FROM Event`?

Comment: one more question, is it also possible to use in the same query to get the name from the user object by passing the ownerid?

Comment: Sure, `SELECT Owner.Name, Owner.Email FROM Event` etc will run just fine!

Comment: SELECT Subject, StartDateTime, Owner.Name, Owner.Email, Notes_Universal_ID__c, Location, IsPrivate, IsDeleted, Id, EndDateTime, Description,
(SELECT EventId, RelationId, Relation.Email FROM EventRelations)
FROM Event - this seems to work fine.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Relation.Email will not work, you should specify type of relation, ie: SELECT Id, (SELECT TYPEOF Relation WHEN Contact THEN Name, Email END FROM EventRelations) FROM Event